# make datetime timezone aware

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have following pandas dataframe column 'datetime':

```
0     2022-05-10 19:44:54.993268+03:00
1     2022-05-10 19:44:54.989526+03:00
2     2022-05-10 19:44:54.985980+03:00
3     2022-05-10 19:44:54.981855+03:00
4     2022-05-10 19:44:54.978606+03:00
5     2022-05-10 19:44:54.963795+03:00
6     2022-05-10 19:44:54.900888+03:00
7     2022-05-10 19:44:54.782925+03:00
8     2022-05-10 19:44:54.724647+03:00
9     2022-05-10 19:44:54.718475+03:00
10    2022-05-10 19:44:54.712729+03:00
11    2022-05-10 19:44:54.708497+03:00
12    2022-05-10 19:44:54.689855+03:00
13    2022-05-10 00:00:01.000001+00:00
```

If I try to convert the

```
pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
```

I got following error:

```
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

But to me it seems like all datetimes are date-time aware.

How can I avoid adding utc=True?

Comment: How deep do you need the time to go? Do you only it until the +? so instead of 2022-05-10 00:00:01.000001+00:00 it would b 2022-05-10 00:00:01.000001?

Comment: you have mixed UTC offsets in your input. the built-in pandas datetime data type cannot handle this unless you convert everything to UTC (you then loose the offset information of course, but you can still keep the original column...). Alternatively, you must use native Python datetime, which means datetime functionality like the .dt accessor aren't available.

Comment: @FObersteiner what exactly do you mean with mixed UTC offsets?

Comment: e.g. rows 12 and 13 in your example have UTC offsets of +3 hours ("+03:00") and zero ("+00:00"). Besides, your data seems to originate from different time zones; like mixed UTC offsets, that's also not supported by pandas datetime64[ns] (within one pd.Series).